# Node-red: trouble with Global variable

Tags: node-red

I have to use the global or flow persistant variables and i have troubles on some uses: It's ok when using it in an simple function, i have a good return message with the good vakue (using .set or .get) but when i try to get the variable in a script to send it to an html page it doesn't work ! (using the same syntax)

An idea ? My node-red below

```
[{"id":"1aed4db1.318612","type":"tab","label":"Flow 2","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8165070c.f8bec8","type":"template","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"html","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n <head>\n  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n  \n  \n </head>\n <body onload=\"draw();\">\n   <canvas id=\"canvas\" width=\"500\" height=\"500\"></canvas>\n    <script>{{{payload.draw}}}</script>\n </body>\n</html>\n\n\n\n","output":"str","x":410,"y":200,"wires":[["e46f2202.f0adb"]]},{"id":"6460da00.6d5c68","type":"http in","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","url":"/test","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":60,"y":200,"wires":[["6d9dba5b.d5a514"]]},{"id":"e46f2202.f0adb","type":"http response","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":630,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"94994060.2fe75","type":"debug","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":500,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"9a0d36a3.66cc08","type":"function","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","func":"total=flow.get(\"test\");\nmsg.payload=total;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":310,"y":140,"wires":[["94994060.2fe75"]]},{"id":"d76ddfb4.1bee6","type":"inject","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":80,"y":140,"wires":[["9a0d36a3.66cc08"]]},{"id":"946553b2.76d2f","type":"config","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"","properties":[{"p":"test","pt":"flow","to":"\"essai\"","tot":"str"}],"active":true,"x":90,"y":80,"wires":[]},{"id":"6d9dba5b.d5a514","type":"template","z":"1aed4db1.318612","name":"Draw","field":"payload.draw","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"    function draw() {\n        var canvas = document.getElementById(\"canvas\");\n        var ctx2 = canvas.getContext(\"2d\");\n        ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';\n        ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);\n        ctx2.fillText(flow.get(\"test\"),200,20);\n     }\n","output":"str","x":210,"y":200,"wires":[["8165070c.f8bec8"]]}]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code from the function/template node, then we do not have to install your flow to work out what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are tying to use `flow.get()` in the body of your template node. That will not work as that code is executing on the remote broker that has no access to anything actually running in Node-RED.

If you want to include flow/context variables, you need to add them to `msg` object you pass to the template node and then use the mustache syntax to substitute them into the template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have made it  and it works but partially...

I've added  "essai={{payload}};"  in my template i  get the value from the message but not totally ! for example if i send a array like [100,200,300,400], in the debug output that's ok: the msg is sending the same thing, but in my template i've only got the first element: "100"... i tried to convert it to string but with the same result..

How get i can get the entire array or value from "essai={{payload}};" ?
my code in the template node:

```
  function draw() {

var essai=[];
            essai={{payload}};
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
             ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
            ctx.fillText(essai, 100,100);
    }
```

And the function node used to send the msg:

```
var total=[];
total=flow.get("agvs_montage");
msg.payload=total;

return msg;
```

the value sent is [100,200,300,400] and the filltext display only "100"...

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask follow up questions. Edit the original question to add details and you can use comments to ask for clarification.